# OPAM and OCaml installation

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop, ocaml-core

I'm having some problems setting up my OCaml environment set up, and am following this page:

https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions

However, I'm having some problems that I can't resolve. I'm on macOS 10.12.5 and am using zsh.

Brew installs opam with no errors or warnings. I believe my problems are with environment variables (??) not being in sync. Here are some outputs when I run some suggested commands:

**opam switch:**

```
--     -- 4.04.2  Official 4.04.2 release
--     -- 4.05.0  Official 4.05.0 release
system  C system  System compiler (4.05.0)
# 251 more patched or experimental compilers, use '--all' to show

[WARNING] The environment is not in sync with the current switch.
          You should run: eval `opam config env`
```

**eval 'opam config env':**

```
CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Users/Alex/.opam/system/lib/stublibs:/usr/local/lib/ocaml/stublibs"; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
OPAMUTF8MSGS="1"; export OPAMUTF8MSGS;
MANPATH="/Users/Alex/.opam/system/man:"; export MANPATH;
PERL5LIB="/Users/Alex/.opam/system/lib/perl5"; export PERL5LIB;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH="/Users/Alex/.opam/system/lib/toplevel"; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
PATH="/Users/Alex/.opam/system/bin:/usr/local/opt/opencv3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS"; export PATH;
```

**opam install base:**

```
The following actions will be performed:
  ∗  install sexplib v0.9.2                   [required by base]
  ∗  install base    v0.9.3
===== ∗  2 =====
Do you want to continue ? [Y/n] y

=-=- Gathering sources =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[base] Archive in cache
[sexplib] Archive in cache

=-=- Processing actions -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[ERROR] The compilation of sexplib failed at "jbuilder build -p sexplib -j 4".

#=== ERROR while installing sexplib.v0.9.2 ====================================#
# opam-version 1.2.2
# os           darwin
# command      jbuilder build -p sexplib -j 4
# path         /Users/Alex/.opam/system/build/sexplib.v0.9.2
# compiler     system (4.05.0)
# exit-code    127
# env-file     /Users/Alex/.opam/system/build/sexplib.v0.9.2/sexplib-35995-e7966f.env
# stdout-file  /Users/Alex/.opam/system/build/sexplib.v0.9.2/sexplib-35995-e7966f.out
# stderr-file  /Users/Alex/.opam/system/build/sexplib.v0.9.2/sexplib-35995-e7966f.err



=-=- Error report -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
The following actions were aborted
  ∗  install base v0.9.3
The following actions failed
  ∗  install sexplib v0.9.2
No changes have been performed
```

For the question's purpose I am showing my attempt at installing base, but would eventually like to install core, utop, oasis etc... Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I was using apostrophes (') when I should have been using backticks (`). Evidence of an inexperienced shell user I suppose...

Comment: Have you tried to run `opam update` and `opam upgrade` first?

Comment: Yep, just tried these and ran eval again. Still having the same problems as before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use backticks (found to the left of the key `1` on many keyboards) when you're doing

```
eval `opam config env`
```

If you have trouble finding the backticks, then you can use an alternative shell syntax

```
eval $(opam config env)
```

Note: this command shouldn't print anything, the fact that you see the values of environment variables indicates that you're calling it wrong (this variables should be seen by the shell).

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. That appears to have solved all my issues. Thank you so much!